# Youtube API v3 - Get "Live Now" rtmp and streamkey

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

Youtube now has a Live Streaming section that allows users to broadcast their own live stream sessions. In this "Live Streaming" section, there are 2 options: "Live Now [Beta]" and "Events".

- Live Now is a fast and easy way to start a streaming session automatically just by pointing your video encoder to te specified RTMP Url and Stream Key. It will automatically detect incomming media and start broadcasting publicly.
- Events is pretty much the same thing, but with advance settings, although it will not start automatically to broadcast, and you need to set everything pretty much manually.

I know Youtube API allows you to retrieve Event's ingestion url and streamkey, so you can broadcast to that target, but it also requires to manage many other steps manually (like publishing the stream, binding broadcasts with streams, check the status, start, stop, etc..). On the other hand "Live Now" makes everything automatically.

Question: How can I retrieve "Live Now" ingestion info (rtmp url and streamkey) from the Youtube API v3 ?

Comment: Hi omarojo, have you found how to get it? I'm also looking for that API and seems YouTube verified programs like "XSplit" and "Wirecast" can get the stream name via API.

Comment: @rhbc73 I managed to use the API to create my own liveBroadcasts and liveStreams (probably the same thing that wirecast, etc are doing). Although Youtube recently updated their API documentation to provide the default ingestion data fornthe Youtube Livestream Now feature, in their liveBroadcast.list endpoint. Still I havent been able to confirm that.

Comment: I know we can create a live broadcast, create a live stream, bind the broadcast to stream, and then stream to the stream name (which is a property of live stream). But the stream name will be different from the one that "Stream now" has. So that the broadcast you created doesn't appear in "Stream now" but appears in "Events" section?

Comment: That is correct. The only benefit of using the "stream now" ingestion end points is that the live event starts and ends acordong to when you start/stop sending video data with your encoder. Otherwise using Live Events requires you to take care of all the livebroadcast cycle, specialy transitioning to a -conplete- status (ending the event)

Comment: Thanks omarojo, that's correct, use live events requires you manually "start preview" and "start streaming" on YouTube webpage. Do you know if these two actions can be performed by some APIs(transition API?)  instead of mouse click on YouTube web page? You also said "Youtube recently updated their API documentation to provide the default ingestion data fornthe Youtube Livestream Now feature", do you have a link to it? (I tried to get it via liveBroadcast.list but nothing returned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot retrieve "Live Now" ingestion info because the API does not differentiate between "Live Now" and "Events."  Those two options are provided as interfaces on top of the API for an end user, so they don't have to write their own application that interfaces with the API.

You will have to manually set up `liveBroadcast` and `liveStream` objects, bind them with [`liveBroadcasts.bind`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind), test your stream, and transition to live on the `liveStream` object using [`status.streamStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#status.streamStatus).

Answer (score 12):

The default broadcast can be retrieved by livebroadcasts.list with broadcastType set to "persistent".

The default livestream can be retrieved by livestreams.list using boundstreamid.

Comment: Thanks for this! Unless you read all of the small print in the docs there is no way of knowing that you can retrieve the default live broadcast

Comment: Wow! It's work like a charm!

Is there any way to obtain the public URL to distribute to the viewers?

Comment: Thank you so much! @ben.bourdin Where can I find the official documentation for this ?

Comment: @deadbeef this is the main resource I used: [youtube live api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/). Each endpoint has an 'API explorer' which works quite well so you can test it easily

Answer (score 2):

To Get “Live Now” rtmp and streamkey

```
       $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts(
            'id,snippet,contentDetails',
            array(
                'broadcastType' => 'persistent',
                'mine' => 'true',
            ));

        $boundStreamId = $broadcastsResponse['items']['0']['contentDetails']['boundStreamId'];

        $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->listLiveStreams('id,snippet,cdn', array(
//            'mine' => 'true',
            'id' => $boundStreamId
        ));

        print_r($streamsResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Keep client_id,client_secret and redirect_uri the client_secrets.json
 UserCredential credential;
 string BoundStreamId = string.Empty;
 string StreamKey=string.Empty;
 using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, 
   FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
             );
            }
if (credential != null)
            {
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "MyApp" // your app name
                });
 LiveBroadcastsResource.ListRequest lbRequest = youtubeService.LiveBroadcasts.List("id,snippet,contentDetails,status");
                lbRequest.BroadcastType = LiveBroadcastsResource.ListRequest.BroadcastTypeEnum.Persistent;
                lbRequest.MaxResults = 10;

                lbRequest.Mine = true;

                var bcResponse = await lbRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                IEnumerator<LiveBroadcast> iLB = bcResponse.Items.GetEnumerator();
                while (iLB.MoveNext() && string.IsNullOrEmpty(liveChatId))
                {
                  BoundStreamId = livebroadcast.ContentDetails.BoundStreamId;
                }
 LiveStreamsResource.ListRequest lsRequest =
                                   youtubeService.LiveStreams.List("id,snippet,cdn,status");
                lsRequest.MaxResults = 50;                    
                lsRequest.Id = BoundStreamId;

                var srResponse = await lsRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                IEnumerator<LiveStream> iLS = srResponse.Items.GetEnumerator();
 if (srResponse != null)
                {
                 foreach(LiveStream lvStream in srResponse.Items)
                    {
                       StreamKey= lvStream.Cdn.IngestionInfo.StreamName);
                    }
                }
          }
```