# YouTube liveStreaming API method LiveStream.list doesn't return stream proposed by YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have stumbled upon an unexpected behavior of [YouTube liveStream API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started).

Whenever I request `liveStream.list` method, the only streams I get back are the ones initiated by my encoding software or `liveStream.insert` calls.

What I am trying to retrieve instead is the stream that is proposed by YouTube in the 
default encoder setup:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems this is not possible. Reading through this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798901/youtube-api-v3-get-live-now-rtmp-and-streamkey), there's no way of doing this yet.
However you can try to manually set up liveBroadcast and liveStream objects, bind them with liveBroadcasts.bind, test your stream, and transition to live on the liveStream object using status.streamStatus

Comment: A `broadcast` (aka event) must have a `stream` (though the data may come later), and the issue is you're on a `broadcast` page, so YouTube auto-generates the `stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve information about the default, or "Stream Now" broadcast by passing *persistent* for the *broadcastType* parameter in [liveBroadcast.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list).

Answer (score 1):

**Here's my final complete code for this** , `$api_stream_url` contains `ServerURL/StreamKey`

[listLiveBroadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) **persistent** – Return only persistent broadcasts.

[listLiveStreams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list) **cdn** - `format`, `rtmp`, `streamName`, `ingestionAddress`

```
try {

    // Execute an API request that lists broadcasts owned by the user who
    // authorized the request.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts(
        'id,snippet,contentDetails',
        array(
            'broadcastType' => 'persistent',
            'mine' => 'true',
        ));

    $boundStreamId = $broadcastsResponse['items']['0']['contentDetails']['boundStreamId'];

    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->listLiveStreams('id,snippet,cdn', array(
//            'mine' => 'true',
        'id' => $boundStreamId
    ));


    /**
     *
     * (
    [format] => 720p
    [ingestionType] => rtmp
    [ingestionInfo] => Array
    (
    [streamName] => 4vem-9233-mz3y-detq
    [ingestionAddress] => rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2
    [backupIngestionAddress] => rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1
    )

    [resolution] => 720p
    [frameRate] => 30fps
    )
     */
    $ingestionInfo = $streamsResponse['items']['0']['cdn']['ingestionInfo'];

    /**
     *  (
    [publishedAt] => 2016-06-08T12:58:38.000Z
    [channelId] => UCcdDtElpr9XM5MA1stpK
    [title] => Default Stream
    [description] =>
    [isDefaultStream] => 1
    )
     */
    $broadcastsResponse = $streamsResponse['items']['0']['snippet'];


    $api_stream_key = $ingestionInfo->streamName;
    $api_stream_address = $ingestionInfo->ingestionAddress;

    /**
     * Example:
     * rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/4vem-9233-mz3y-detq
     */
    $api_stream_url = $api_stream_address."/".$api_stream_key;


    return false;

} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}
```